# Problems in GAMS (errors 669, 8, 37, 409)

Tags: gams-math

I'm getting a few errors in my code (which is interfaced with Matlab) and I'm unable to solve them.

```
26  $if exists $ include matdata.gms
****            $668
```

1 - Can't understand this error and can't find information about it.

```
 58  PiCalc(b,t)..                    Pi(b,t) =e= P(b,t) + c(b,t) - d(b,t);
****                                     $37,409

 37  '=l=' or '=e=' or '=g=' operator expected
```

2 - I don't understand what the problem is here as I clearly use a '=e=' operator.

```
59  P_linhaCalc(l,t)..               P_linha(l,t) =e= sum(b, A(l,b)*Pi(b,t));
****                                                                    $8,409
 8  ')' expected
 409  Unrecognizable item - skip to find a new statement
       looking for a ';' or a key word to get started again
```

3 - Again, I don't understand the missing ')' when It's present.

Any feedback is appreciated.

Full code is bellow:

```
** Define the structure to connect with the matlab code
*$onempty
$include matglobs.gms
*$if exists $ include matdata.gms

set      t /1*%timeSteps%/,
         b /1*%bus%/,
         l /1*%lines%/
         ;

Positive Variable d(b,t),
                  c(b,t)
                  ;

Free Variable res;

parameters       size(b), rate(b),lim_linhas(l), P(b,t), A(l,b),
                 cost, soc(b,t),
                 P_linha(l,t),
                 pen, bat(b), preco(t)
                 ;

$if exists $ include matdata.gms

Equations

socCalc1(b,t)
socCalc2(b,t)
maxDischarge(b,t)
maxCharge(b,t)
PiCalc(b,t)
P_linhaCalc(l,t)
penCalc(l,t)
Con10(b)
Con11
Obj
;

socCalc1(b,t)$(ord(t)=1)..      soc(b,t) =e= size(b)/2;
socCalc2(b,t)$(ord(t)>1)..      soc(b,t) =e= soc(b,t-1) + c(b,t) - d(b,t);

maxDischarge(b,t)..              d(b,t) =l= rate(b)*size(b);
maxCharge(b,t)..                 c(b,t) =l= rate(b)*size(b);

PiCalc(b,t)..                    Pi(b,t) =e= P(b,t)+c(b,t)-d(b,t);

P_linhaCalc(l,t)..               P_linha(l,t) =e= sum(b, A(l,b)*Pi(b,t));

penCalc(l,t)$(P_linha(l,t) > lim_linhas(l))..  pen =e= pen - (P_linha(l,t) - lim_linhas(l))*100000;

Con10(b)..                       sum(t, d(b,t)*preco(t) - c(b,t)*preco(t)) =e= bat(b);
Con11..                          sum(b, bat(b)) =e= cost;

Obj..                            cost + pen =e= res;

Model Opt_Bat /all/;

Solve Opt_Bat using MINLP minimizing res;

$libinclude matout res.l
```

Comment: All you show is GAMS code, thus I removed the MATLAB tag for now. If there is any indication that MATLAB is in any way related to this error, please share the relevant MATLAB parts as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1:

```
26  $if exists $ include matdata.gms
****            $668
```

> 1 - Can't understand this error and cant find information about it.

The explanation text for error 668 is: "$if [NOT] unquoted command is ambiguous, use quotes around expression". The problem is, that you are a little off the correct syntax here. You probably want to write the following?

```
$if exist matdata.gms $include matdata.gms
```

2/3:

```
58  PiCalc(b,t)..                    Pi(b,t) =e= P(b,t) + c(b,t) - d(b,t);
****                                     $37,409

 37  '=l=' or '=e=' or '=g=' operator expected
```

> 2 - I dont understand whats the problem here as I clearly use a '=e=' operator.

You do not define any symbol called `pi`. But there is a GAMS "function" called `pi`: https://www.gams.com/latest/docs/UG_Parameters.html#INDEX_functions_22_pi This does not have any arguments, so that the opening `(` causes the error here. So you probably miss the declaration of "your" `pi` which would overwrites the GAMS `pi`. Your point 3 has the same cause